# I think my code is correct But it is not working it is with opencv ,i trying to get my camera

Tags: python

```
import cv2

vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,frame=vid.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in
function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you loop this line of code, the loop starts the camera and stops the camera:

```
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You should try this code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
# The device number might be 0 or 1 depending on the device and the webcam
cap.open(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow it's always appreciated if you add a little explanation why the code answers the question. Answers are mainly for future  readers for which Stack Overflow is building a knowledge base.